# TwoPHP blocks in file

Tags: php, html, forms, block

i have two HTML forms and two PHP blocks in one file (index.php). for example i want the second php script belonged to the second form. i dont know, how to do it. What i write to the action atribute ?

here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="htmlspecialchars $_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]">
<input type="text" name="name"> <br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form method="post" action="htmlspecialchars $_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]">
<input type="text" name="age"> <br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
echo $_POST ["name"];
?>

<?php
echo $_POST ["age"]; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps you,

First form,

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"];?> ">
        <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
        <input type="submit" name='submit' >
    </form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            echo $_POST ["name"];
    }
?>
```

Second form

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"];?>">
        <input type="text" name="age"> <br>
        <input type="submit" name='submitsecond' > // name submitsecond indicates as second form
    </form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submitsecond'])){
            echo $_POST ["age"];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden input field to distinguish both scripts. And you'll have to echo/print the script name (`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`), htmlspecialchars is not needed...

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="name_form" />
    <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="age_form" />
    <input type="text" name="age"> <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php if($_POST['form'] == 'name_form'): ?>
    The name form is submitted.<br>
    Name: <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($_POST['form'] == 'age_form'): ?>
    The age form is submitted.<br>
    Age: <?php echo $_POST['age']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
<input type="text" name="name"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="name_sub">
</form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST ["name_sub"])) // check if name form is submit
    echo $_POST ["name"]; 
    ?>
```

Comment: `action="htmlspecialchars $_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]"` This is plain wrong, for starter.

Comment: Do you think that will work? Check the action attr of the form!